# test_train_split with stratify integer overflow

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do a stratified split for a skewed dataset with target variable 'b'. The target variable is a bit value (either 0 or 1). Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': np.random.rand(100000), 'b': 0})
df.loc[np.random.randint(0, 100000, 1000), 'b'] = 1
tr, ts = train_test_split(df, test_size=.2, stratify=df['b'])
print(tr.shape, ts.shape)
```

This code returns the following:

```
(93105, 2) (38, 2)
```

My problem is that the returned train/test arrays do not meet the set split ratio of 20%.

My setup:

- Python 3.7.0 (**32bit**)
- Sklearn 0.20.3
- Pandas 0.23.4

I discovered that the problem is resulting from an integer overflow in the underlying split function.

How can I resolve this issue and is this a known bug? I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to apply to Python 3.7.x (64bit).

Comment: I'm glad to see that you(?) posted this as an issue on skl's github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13794

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
# Split the data between the Training Data and Test Data
xTrain , xTest , yTrain , yTest = train_test_split(X , y , 
                                                  test_size = 0.30 , 
                                                  random_state = 0, 
                                          ----->  stratify = y)
```